# ADAL AcquireTokenAsync doesn't want parent window

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, adal

I want to add Azure AD authentication to my desktop application, so I have an OAuth2 access token I can use for a web API. The authentication itself is working, my problem is the `parentWindow`. I don't want my form to be accessible/clickable as long as an authentication window is visible. But every time I specify my main form as `parentWindow`, I get an `InvalidOperationException` with the message:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'FormMain' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

If I specify just the form's handle as `parentWindow` parameter (it just requires an `object`), it says "BrowserAuthenticationWindow" instead of "FormMain", but the error is the same. This is the line of code where the error occurs:

```
var token = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
    resourceUri, ClientId, new Uri(redirectUri),
    new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto, parentWindow));
    //                      also doesn't work:  parentWindow.Handle
```

I also tried to avoid the error by using `InvokeRequired`, but it didn't work.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: No, I'd have answered the question myself if I did.

Answer (score 0):

At this point I believe this to be a bug in the Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory nuget introduced in version 3.18 and will be opening an issue on their GitHub repo. If you can downgrade to version 3.17.3, you will see that the same code works and there is no cross-thread exception thrown.

[Issue opened on github](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/1277)